# Lua - C API - Create variables before running

Tags: c, lua

I would like to extend the Lua so that when a user writes a script, a variable is already available to him. This variable should be an instance of a custom class.

For that I'm doing `lua_newuserdata` and `lua_setglobal( L, "variableName" );` on the Lua stack before running the script.

Them problem is that it is crashing, so I'm not sure if it is crashing because I'm attempting to create object instances before running the script or because I have another error somewhere else.

Is it allowed to create object instances before running a LUA script ? And if not, what other way do I have to create a variable that is initially present in the globals without the user havingto do anything to retreive it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you create a new `lua_State` before adding your variable?

Comment: There isn't really a concept of "running a Lua script". You create a state, then you push a function onto the stack (e.g. with `lua_load`), and then you call that function. Lua execution is driven by the host. There's no "running machine" in way that you might expect from other languages.

Comment: Yes I have (using luaL_newstate()). Also your comment made me realize that I do have to right to create a global before running the script. just like in this example (http://lua-users.org/wiki/UserDataExample) so I must have another error. The crash in occuring when lua_newuserdata calls luaC_checkGC

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually I just passed a NULL pointer instead of the stack... Sorry for the waste of time... I'll close this question.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of expected that to be the case. Delete away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to extend the Lua so that when a user writes a script, a variable is already available to him.

That is certainly possible. Once the Lua state exists you can create global variables (ie. place key/value pairs in the global environment table).

> Is it allowed to create object instances before running a LUA script ?

Yes it is. In my code I preload all sorts of stuff. Tables of useful things for the end-user. Extra libraries they can call.

Example code:

```C++
typedef struct { const char* key; int val; } flags_pair;
...
static flags_pair trigger_flags[] =
{
  { "Enabled", 1 },  // enable trigger 
  { "OmitFromLog", 2 },  // omit from log file 
  { "OmitFromOutput", 4 },  // omit trigger from output 
  { "KeepEvaluating", 8 },  // keep evaluating 
  { "IgnoreCase", 16 },  // ignore case when matching 
  { "RegularExpression", 32 },  // trigger uses regular expression 
  { "ExpandVariables", 512 },  // expand variables like @direction 
  { "Replace", 1024 },  // replace existing trigger of same name 
  { "LowercaseWildcard", 2048 },   // wildcards forced to lower-case
  { "Temporary", 16384 },  // temporary - do not save to world file 
  { "OneShot", 32768 },  // if set, trigger only fires once 
  { NULL, 0 }
};
...
static int MakeFlagsTable (lua_State *L, 
                           const char *name,
                           const flags_pair *arr)
{
  const flags_pair *p;
  lua_newtable(L);
  for(p=arr; p->key != NULL; p++) {
    lua_pushstring(L, p->key);
    lua_pushnumber(L, p->val);
    lua_rawset(L, -3);
  }
  lua_setglobal (L, name);
  return 1;
}
...
  MakeFlagsTable (L, "trigger_flag", trigger_flags)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help.